# React | Node application | Docker deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, couchbase

I am kind of new to this, have react frontend and Node backend end application created and trying to deploy in docker, but its throwing the below error. Can someone pls help me why python is being referred, and why couchbase installation is having issues?

Package.json file has

```
{
  "name": "XPress",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^3.10.8",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "2.8.5",
    "couchbase": "^2.6.11",
    "dva": "^2.4.1",
    "dva-loading": "^2.0.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "pg": "^7.18.2",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
      "sourceType": "module",
      "allowImportExportEverywhere": true
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

**Error**

```
TestUser-8681:Utility TestUser$ docker build . -t xpressimg
Sending build context to Docker daemon  434.4MB
Step 1/7 : FROM  node:alpine
 ---> 483343d6c5f5
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /xpress
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fc35b4f51420
Step 3/7 : COPY package*.json ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5593b2fe0b05
Step 4/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in f00b67e0b069
> couchbase@2.6.11 install /xpress/node_modules/couchbase
> prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
prebuild-install WARN install unable to get local issuer certificate
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="/path/to/pythonexecutable"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "/path/to/pythonexecutable"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:307:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:136:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:179:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:271:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:310:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:322:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.76-linuxkit
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /xpress/node_modules/couchbase
gyp ERR! node -v v13.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! couchbase@2.6.11 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the couchbase@2.6.11 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-03-28T03_12_19_475Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

appreciate your support on this regard

After the provided suggestion, i see below error
Sending build context to Docker daemon  434.4MB
[WARNING]: Empty continuation line found in:
    RUN apk add --update-cache     python     python-dev     py-pip     build-base WORKDIR /xpress
[WARNING]: Empty continuation lines will become errors in a future release.
Step 1/7 : FROM  node:alpine
 ---> 483343d6c5f5
Step 2/7 : RUN apk add --update-cache     python     python-dev     py-pip     build-base WORKDIR /xpress
 ---> Running in e587974d8218
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  /xpress (missing):
    required by: world[/xpress]
  WORKDIR (missing):
    required by: world[WORKDIR]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --update-cache     python     python-dev     py-pip     build-base WORKDIR /xpress' returned a non-zero code: 2

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, [node-gyp depends on a Python interpreter in the environment](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-unix) and couchbase depends on node-gyp to be installed. You must install Python in your Docker container.

Considering you are using `alpine:node`, you can install it via `apk`:

```
RUN apk add --update-cache \
    python \
    python-dev \
    py-pip \
    build-base
```

Add this command before running `npm install`.

This sample is taken from here: https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/master/docs/usage.md#example

**UPDATE**

I'm sorry, my response was incomplete. You need to install some other dependencies, and remove them after running npm install. Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/mhart/alpine-node/issues/27#issuecomment-390187978

**Note that npm install is ran between `apk add` and `apk del`, so build dependencies, such as python, are not bundled in your image**

```
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps make gcc g++ python \
 && npm install --production --silent \
 && apk del .build-deps
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried the above suggestion, unable to add the whole error, so I have added in original post. I still see few errors.

Comment: I'm sorry, my response was incomplete. You need to install some other dependencies, and remove them after running npm install. Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/mhart/alpine-node/issues/27#issuecomment-390187978

Comment: Thanks once again, Image is built ,  TestUser$ docker run  ximghjgdddsk
/xpress/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:121
        throw e;
        ^Error: Error loading shared library /xpress/node_modules/couchbase/build/Release/couchbase_impl.node: Exec format error, My latest docker file is as below

Comment: FROM  node:alpine
    
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /xpress
# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps make gcc g++ python \
 && npm install --production --silent \
 && apk del .build-deps

COPY package*.json ./

# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]

Comment: Your Dockerfile's commands are quite out of order.

You need to copy `package*.json` before running `npm install`, or else you are just installing an empty package. `npm ci` is not needed, as it runs `npm install`. Also, you have two `CMD` statements. Is this expected?